# Como juntar dois selects de tabelas distintas?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
+--------- +      +-------------+
| usuario  |      |usuario_grupo|     +----------+
+--------- +      +-------------+     | grupo    |
|usuario_id|----->| membro_id   |     +----------+
| nome     |      | grupo_id    |<----| grupo_id |
| ....     |      +-------------+     | nome     | 
| ...      |                          +----------+                          
+----------+
```

Gostaria de fazer uma query em que eu obtivesse utilizando um foreach, por exemplo, o seguinte:

Todos os grupos que um determinado usuário está, e todos os membros que pertence do grupo em questão.

A principio consigo obter os grupos (estou utilizando o codeigniter).:

```
$q = $this->db->select('grupo_id')->from('usuario_grupo')->where('membro_id', $membro_id)->get()->result_array();
foreach ($q as $v) {
       $result[] = $this->db->select()->from('grupo')->where_in('grupo_id', $v)->get()->row_array();
}
```

Resultado em Json, por exemplo:

```
[
    {
      "grupo_id": "1",
      "nome": "São Paulo",
    }
    {
      "grupo_id": "9",
      "nome": "Rio de Janeiro",
    }
]
```

No entanto, gostaria de obter também os membros de cada grupo obtido:

```
[
    {
      "grupo_id": "1",
      "nome": "São Paulo",
      "membros": 
                {
                  "membro_id": "21",
                  "membro_id": "39"
                }
    }
    {
      "grupo_id": "9",
      "nome": "Rio de Janeiro",
      "membros": 
               {
                 "membro_id": "4",
                 "membro_id": "9"
               }
    }
]
```

Comment: Você pode postar a estrutura de suas tabelas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma mais correta no codeigniter de você fazer isto, penso eu, que seja da forma que vou expor a seguir, usando o join e montando um subarray() para os resultados esperados:

```
public function get_usuarios(){
    $consulta = $this->db->get('usuario')->result();
    foreach($consulta as &$valor){
        $this->db->select('usuario_grupo.*, grupo.nome as nome_grupo');
        $this->db->where('id_usuario', $valor->id_usuario); // neste caso é o id do usuário
        $this->db->join("grupo", "grupo.grupo_id=usuario_grupo.grupo_id"); // neste caso, montamos o join para buscar o nome do grupo
        $valor->grupos = $this->db->get('usuario_grupo')->result();
    }

    return $consulta;
}
```

Nisto vamos obter a listagem completa dos usuários e seus respectivos grupos em cada um deles, abaixo deles.

Para você iniciar a pesquisa, você poderá fazer:

```
$retorno = $this->nome_model->get_usuarios();

foreach($retorno->grupos as $valor){    
    echo "Este usuário ".$valor->nome_usuario." pertence ao grupo ".$valor->nome_grupo;
}
```

Comment: No caso, invés de retornar todos os usuários, eu gostaria de retornar todos os grupos com seus respectivos membros. Se possível gostaria que me mostrasse, mas de qualquer forma, sua resposta está correta.